# How to create an extra field with handled data at the same time of pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV with three fields (e.g., 'date', 'worker_group', 'location'). At the same time I read the file with "df = pd.read_csv", I would like to create an extra field within the dataframe (e.g. 'type') that is the result of processing the three fields.

I'm aware of the existence of the converters but, as far as I know, such converters just transform the contents of a particular field, without the possibility of creating extra fields.

I'm considering also the possibility of post-process the resulting dataframe, but I wondered if there was a smart way to do it at the same time of the CSV reading.

Comment: I think it is not possible, given that the read csv, as the name suggests, reads data, and also transform this data, but not create new data.

Comment: You could probably do what you need by chaining on the [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method. ie `pd.read_csv(...).assign(type=...)` without sample data and specific "processing" it's difficult to give any more detail than that.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what you want to do with the additional new field called `type` without understanding the calculation that you're performing using the other 3 fields, however my solution is a contrived example which concatenates the fields together and just treats them as strings for illustrative purposes.

Generally, if you want an additional field, it would be preferable to append this as a new column to the dataframe once you have initally read your csv file into the dataframe. This gives a proper separation of concerns for the different data handling processes (i.e. importing and transforming data). It would look something like this...

```
# Import the Panads library
import pandas as pd

# Read the file into your dataframe `df` using the comma as a delimiter
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=',')

# Add a new column called 'type' and, in this case, use a lambda expression to calculate the contents of the field
df['type'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['date'] + x['worker_group'] + x['location'], axis=1)
```

You will need to adjust the calculation accordingly to whatever *"the result of processing the three fields"* means to you.